# How can I display an image larger than the screen and allow the user to scroll to see more?

Tags: android, graphics-design, multiple-graphics-devices

I am new to development and trying to understand my options.  I have found no info or threads on this idea so I was hoping some of you folks could weigh in.

When developing for Android, I know that different images optimized for different screen densities and sizes are typically used.  I am wondering if anyone just flicks in the resizing and develops so that the smallest device (i.e. phone) shows enough of say a game world to make it relevant for the user and larger screens (i.e. tablet) just show more of that world but at the same scale.

I guess you would have to have a couple versions for different densities or graphics could appear too small, but it could really cut down on the number of asset files the user would have to download.  Though the whole background/world image would be one big file.  I assume when downloading an app graphics files for all screen sizes and resolutions are downloaded and then the app detects the screen size and chooses from among them for display.

Comment: I think this happens in many games, perhaps e.g. in a strategy game if you have a bigger device you just see more of the map if you view it in same size.

Comment: The title and contents don't seem to match up here. Are you looking for a way to let users pan a large image (title) or for techniques of making graphics for differently-sized screens (body)?

Comment: Anko,  Sorry I didn't think that was my original title.  Maybe I accidently had more than one window open at this site.  I am interested in letting users move their character/marker over a map that is bigger than the device screen.  I am not sure if this is panning or not.   Antont - I will try to see if I can find info on this in strategy games perhaps.  Thanks.